# rails 4 find and show last/specific db entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make webpages that can show the first, last and specific db entries.

It works fine with all and first but I have difficulties with the other two.

Users_controller

```
   def index
    @user = User.all.order("id desc")
  end

  def one
    @user = User.find(1)
  end

  def last
    @user = User.order("created_at").last
  end

  def specific
    #@user = User.
  end

  def cinderella
    @user = User.where("username = 'Cinderella'")
  end
```

def one and def cinderella are working well but I have no idea how to retrieve the last entry as well as only a few attributes(like the username only) for the specific method.

(The task is to define almost everything in the controller)

My second problem is to show what I filtered.

I used the following code to show the cinderella one but if I use the same code for the last entry it always says that the 'each' is undefined..

```
<div class="Sign_Form">
  <% @user.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <%= u.username %>  
        <%= link_to 'Delete', user_path(u), method: :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'%>
        <hr>
        <br>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Chrizzly

Comment: Go through [Getting Started with Rails: Getting up and running quickly with scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) section. Parts of it show how to show all entries, an individual entry, etc. You will be in a better position to figure these questions out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying the each is undefined because when you are retrieving the last user you are only getting back one object, not an array of objects therefore there is nothing to loop over. You can simply just call @user.username in the html.

Comment: yeah thanks the error message is gone :) but it seems like i have a mistake in the controller(it doesn't show the entry )